# Is there a way to pass agGroupCellRenderer params to custom component on click of expansion arrow in ag-grid?

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

On click of expansion arrow of row "Mila Smith", I want to pass row data to custom component which is inside the row expansion.

[image: Ag-grid]